# Aligning separate links tp the right

Tags: html, css

I have this navigation bar and I want two separate links to the right. But it seems putting float: right; to my div doesn't work. It aligns with the other elements instead. How do we do this?

```css
    /*css*/
    #navigation {
     background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
        overflow: hidden;
        color: white;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 46px;
        border-top: 1px solid #6a6a6a;

        .navigation-links-left {
         width: max-content;
         padding: 15px 0px;
         border-left: 1px solid #6a6a6a;
         margin: 0px;
         a {
          padding: 15px 16px;
           border-right: 1px solid #6A6A6A;
           margin: -3px;
         }
     }

     .navigation-links-right {
          float: right;
     }
    }
```

```html
    <!-- HTML-->
    <div id="navigation">
      <div class="wrapper">
     <div class="navigation-links-left">
     <a><img src="images/icon/icon_nav_03.png"></a>
     <a>KU 스타트업 <img src="images/icon/icon_nav_04.png"></a>
     <a>인사말</a>
      <div class="navigation-links-right">
       <a><img src="images/icon/icon_nav_01.png"></a>
       <a><img src="images/icon/icon_nav_02.png"></a>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Are you using Sass or another CSS extension language? Nesting CSS rules like that is not typically valid if rendered directly in a browser.

Comment: oh sorry i forgot to note im using sass @tshimkus

Answer (score 1):

you need to apply your div `float left` and `float right` see demo below, 
I have also corrected some html from your code you wrapped `navigation-links-right` inside your `navigation-links-left` div so corrected that

```css
/*css*/
#navigation {
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
overflow: hidden;
color: white;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 46px;
border-top: 1px solid #6a6a6a;
}
.navigation-links-left {
    width: max-content;
    padding: 15px 0px;
    border-left: 1px solid #6a6a6a;
    margin: 0px;
    float:left;
    }
    a {
        padding: 15px 16px;
        border-right: 1px solid #6A6A6A;
        margin: -3px;
    }



.navigation-links-right {
    float: right;
    padding: 15px 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="navigation">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="navigation-links-left">
                   <a><img src="images/icon/icon_nav_03.png"></a>
                   <a>KU 스타트업 <img src="images/icon/icon_nav_04.png">
                   </a>
                   <a>인사말</a>
                </div>
              <div class="navigation-links-right">
                <a><img src="images/icon/icon_nav_01.png"></a>
                <a><img src="images/icon/icon_nav_02.png"></a>
              </div>
                
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears your `navigation-links-right` element is nested inside your `navigation-links-left` one. Try bringing it outside:

```css
#navigation {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    overflow: hidden;
    color: white;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 46px;
    border-top: 1px solid #6a6a6a;
}

.navigation-links-left, .navigation-links-right {
    width: max-content;
    padding: 15px 0px;
    display: inline-block;
    border-left: 1px solid #6a6a6a;
    margin: 0px;
}

.navigation-links-left a, .navigation-links-right a {
    padding: 15px 16px;
    border-right: 1px solid #6A6A6A;
    margin: -3px;
}


.navigation-links-right {
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="navigation">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="navigation-links-left">
          <a><img src="images/icon/icon_nav_03.png"></a>
          <a>KU 스타트업 <img src="images/icon/icon_nav_04.png"></a>
          <a>인사말</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navigation-links-right">
          <a><img src="images/icon/icon_nav_01.png"></a>
          <a><img src="images/icon/icon_nav_02.png"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I also believe this is a good application for CSS Flexbox:

```css
#navigation {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    border-top: 1px solid #6a6a6a;
    bottom: 0;
    color: white;
    height: 46px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.navigation-links-left, .navigation-links-right {
    align-items: center;
    border-left: 1px solid #6a6a6a;
    display: inline-flex;
    height: 100%;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.navigation-links-left a, .navigation-links-right a {
    border-right: 1px solid #6A6A6A;
    margin: -3px;
    padding: 15px 16px;
}
```

```html
<div id="navigation">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="navigation-links-left">
          <a><img src="images/icon/icon_nav_03.png"></a>
          <a>KU 스타트업 <img src="images/icon/icon_nav_04.png"></a>
          <a>인사말</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navigation-links-right">
          <a><img src="images/icon/icon_nav_01.png"></a>
          <a><img src="images/icon/icon_nav_02.png"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I forgot to inform you that this is a SASS code.. @jaredgorski

Comment: I changed to normal CSS so that the snippet would display when you run it. It's not difficult to convert between normal CSS and SASS. What matters more is communicating how to get the correct layout using CSS regardless of the way you're compiling it.